# What data structure/db should I use for storing the file tree structure?

Tags: python, database, database-design, data-structures

I am trying to write an application(I am using python) to have a copy of a remote machines directory structure in my local machine (not the actual content of the files in the remote machine).
Once I store it in my local machine, I want to be be able to perform the following operations on my local copy of the tree structure

"ls"

"ls /etc"

"ls /etc/bin/yahoo"

and see the listing. Also if I change/add a dir/file name in the remote machine, I want to have the ability to easily update it in my local data structure.

UPDATE:

Some people suggested using Nested Set Model. I think updating it is an expensive process.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: whats a best/easiest way to store a tree structure from the output of "ls -R" ? I want to keep a copy of this in a local file(/or db) and if anything changes on the remote server, update this file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare a class which has a list of its own type. Basically a simple tree structure. 
For ls:
Just dispay all the child recursively.

For any new addition:
Add it to the parent directory node's child list as a child.